# how to control indentations in code

Tags: beamer

I have a java code which I want to add to a frame.
How do I set the options in `lstset` to make sure that beamer keeps the original indentions  in the code.
For example in the below code the comments are pushed to the left and even the call to function `bar()` is pushed to the left.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{pred}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{pgrey}{rgb}{0.46,0.45,0.48}

\lstset{language=Java
                ,showspaces=true
                ,showtabs=true
                ,showstringspaces=false
                ,tabsize=2
                ,commentstyle=\color{pgreen}
                ,keywordstyle=\color{pblue}
                ,stringstyle=\color{pred}
                ,basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily
                ,breaklines=false
                ,resetmargins=false
                ,autogobble=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{foo}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");

        //comment 1
        blah blah;
        blah blah;      
        //comment 2
        blah blah;
        blah blah;
        foo();  

        bar();
    }
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get this with `miktex`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0uCI5.png.

Comment: i use `texmaker` and `miktex`. Is this something to do with my editor?

Comment: Nothing to do with editor. You can try to update your miktex through package manager.

Comment: i updated `miktex`. But still the same issue. Is this something to do with `lstset`?

Comment: Try `resetmargins=false` in `lstset`. There is also `gobble`. Have you enabled it some where?

Comment: i updated the code and results. Still I dont get the output which you seem to get

Comment: Why `autogobble=true`? Make it false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer will write your inline code to an external file and read it again. During this process, the spaces get lost.

To fix this, use `\defverbatim` as follows.

Just for fun solution.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{pred}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{pgrey}{rgb}{0.46,0.45,0.48}

\lstdefinestyle{java}
{
    ,language=Java
    ,showspaces=false
    ,showtabs=false
    ,showstringspaces=false
    ,tabsize=3
    ,commentstyle=\color{pgreen}
    ,keywordstyle=\color{pblue}
    ,stringstyle=\color{pred}
    ,basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily
    ,breaklines=true
    ,resetmargins=false
    ,autogobble=false
}


\begin{document}
\defverbatim[colored]\Lst{%
\lstlisting[style=java]
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Hello");

    //comment 1
    blah blah;
    blah blah;
    //comment 2
    blah blah;
    blah blah;
    foo();

    bar();
}
\endlstlisting}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{foo}
\Lst
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. And can you point out what was wrong with my approach

Comment: @arunmoezhi: no upvote, no explanation. :-)

Comment: LOL.. no explanation, no upvote ;)